# SQL Server Management Studio query check for data corruption (selects, joins, etc..)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, ssms

I was trying to write a query for two tables (**Receipt** and **ReceiptLine**) find data corruption where a receipt does not contain any lines. I have a .bak of the database file on google drive but not sure if anyone here would want to take the effort to help me that far :D

> **i.e.** Write a query to find data corruption where a receipt does not contain
>   any lines. (HINT: Use the Receipt and ReceiptLine tables). 
>   --    Return the UniqReceipt and ReferNumber columns.

I need to return the 'UniqReceipt' and 'ReferNumber' columns.

It looks like the primary key of **Receipt** table is 'UniqReceipt' column and the primary key of **ReceiptLine** is 'UniqReceiptLine' column, and the foreign key 'UniqReceipt' REFERENCES the column 'UniqReceipt' in the **Receipt** table

The Receipt table looks like this:
[image]

and the ReceiptLine table like this:
[image]

I ended up coming up with this:

```
SELECT r.UniqReceipt, r.ReferNumber
FROM Receipt r
INNER JOIN ReceiptLine l ON r.UniqReceipt = l.UniqReceipt
WHERE datalength(l.ReceiptLineNumber) = 0 OR ReceiptLineNumber = '-1' OR ReceiptLineNumber IS NULL
```

Does anyone know if this the best way to implement this? I basically looked when the ReceiptLineNumber was empty or NULL or '-1' (we use -1 instead of NULL) and joined when UniqReceipt = UniqReceipt in both tables.

I wasn't sure if using variables or some print statement would be better to check for data corruption.

Query result:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is OK except for the INNER JOIN part. That will only show where record is present in both tables. You need to use a LEFT OUTER join instead. That will show all the records from the table on the left and matching records from the table on the right. If you also add a WHERE clause for missing lines, you will get your invalid receipts:

```
SELECT r.UniqReceipt, r.ReferNumber
FROM Receipt r
LEFT OUTER JOIN ReceiptLine l ON r.UniqReceipt = l.UniqReceipt
WHERE l.ReceiptLineNumber IS NULL
```

Comment: It would be even better if you could also show the same query using "not exists".

Answer (score 0):

You can write below query to classify the cases where ReceiptLine is not present and then select only those receipts.

One more thing, you should always represent NULL values in a single way. In one place, you are representing them as -1 and in another place, you are leaving them as NULL and in another place you are leaving them as empty space. It will lead to confusion. I would suggest to simply leave them as NULL, for more clarity, if no receipt lines are present for a receipt.

```
SELECT UniqReceipt,ReferNumber
FROM  
(SELECT r.UniqReceipt
      , r.ReferNumber
      , CASE WHEN l.ReceiptLineNumber = '-1' THEN 0
             WHEN LEN(l.ReceiptLineNumber) = 0 THEN 0
             WHEN l.ReceiptLineNumber IS NULL THEN 0
             ELSE 1 END AS IsReceiptLineNumberPresent                                       
FROM Receipt r
LEFT OUTER JOIN ReceiptLine l ON r.UniqReceipt = l.UniqReceipt) AS t
WHERE IsReceiptLineNumberPresent = 0
```

Comment: There is no good reason to use a derived table or that complicated (and pointless) case expression. That case expression is just a student grasping at straws without understanding - something you should have seen and explained.

Comment: @SMor, As he is telling that he is representing NULL in multiple ways, I wanted to have a uniform representation. I have mentioned to OP, that data storage is not correct